# How to get the rows in Pandas dataframe with datetime index using another datetime index?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing

I have a Pandas dataframe with the following datetime index:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-06', '2020-01-07',
               '2020-01-08', '2020-01-09', '2020-01-10', '2020-01-13',
               '2020-01-14', '2020-01-15',
               ...
               '2020-01-17', '2020-01-21', '2020-01-22', '2020-01-23',
               '2020-01-24', '2020-01-27', '2020-01-28', '2020-01-29',
               '2020-01-30', '2020-01-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', length=49098, freq=None)
```

I want to get the rows which intersect with the following datetime index:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-06', '2020-01-07',
               '2020-01-08', '2020-01-09', '2020-01-10'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq=None)
```

What is the most natural (aka "Pythonic") way to do it?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html):

```
idx = idx1.intersection(idx2)
```

Or, if the indexes have not been previously defined:

```
idx = df1.index.intersection(df2.index)
```

Comment: At your service.

Comment: This is how you get the intersection of two DateTimeIndex as a DateTimeIndex. But how do you get the rows from the original dataframe (which was the original question)? `df.loc[idx]` gives me a dataframe that has more rows than the original `df`. My original `df` has multiple occurances of the same dates.

Comment: @jezrael I knew you are fast, but I did not know you were this fast! Yes, it works.

Comment: thanks @jezrael !  i was searching almost hour looking for clean answer